# Positioning on a responsive site

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I need help with a landing page, it has 4 contents, a logo, header text, description text and button.

The first part is I want everything to resize depending on the browser, if the browser is large then everything gets large, if the browser is small then everything goes small.

The second part is I want the main text to be in the middle of the browser no matter what height it is, I then want the description text just below it and the logo image just above it, finally the button just below the description text.

Here's what I have so far:  http://jsfiddle.net/9wup4wm4/1/

I pretty sure it's the css I need help with which I 've attached but take a look at the demo, I made need help elsewhere.

Here's the css:

```
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
html {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-size: cover;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
background: inherit;
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
font-size: 2em;
/* overflow: hidden; enable to disable scrolling */
background:red;
}
#page-wrapper {
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
.full-content {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
.full-width {
position:absolute;
bottom:10%;
text-align:center;
}
.big-logo {
padding-left:57px;
margin-top:10%;
}
.big-logo img {
height:auto;
width:320px;
}
.big-title {    
font-size: 3em;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight:800;
display: block;
margin-top:5%;
}
.title-description {
font: 12px;
display: block;
margin-top:5%;
}
.button-container {
display: inline-block;
margin-top:5%;
}
.button {
color: #fff;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: 300;
padding: 7px 30px;
cursor: pointer;
vertical-align: middle; 
text-decoration: none;
letter-spacing: 3px;
border: 2px solid;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about media queries? And other things like:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:320px) {
 .selector { font-size: 14px }
}
```

Here others: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/